# Multiple divs with sticky position overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

When i have multiple div's with sticky position the first div is overlapping the second div while at the end and not staying locked at the position without overlapping.
How do i make it lock at a position when it ends the corresponding div

Here is a copepen for that

HTML :

```
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-header">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
```

CSS

```
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;
}
.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0;}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sandeep-chetikam/pen/RwxZOxR)

Original problem in website

https://ibb.co/BCq4Pnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the height of first element i.e( `80px` including border and paddings ) in your case.

Give `80px` top to the second element.

Third element will have a top of `160px` and so on.

All elements will have `position:sticky`

Try this,

```css
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; height:1000px}
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;
}
.main-content{
  min-height:1000px;
}

.main-header{position:sticky; top:0px;}
div.main-header{top:80px }
.main-footer{position:sticky; top:160px }
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-header">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how that would work ?

Comment: @Sourav I will explain if my answer is correct, if it is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes it is what i wanted, I am facing this problem right now in my website [link]https://ibb.co/BCq4Pnd , i have two divs sticky and they are ovelapping eachother at the end of that column

Answer (score 0):

First change the class of your body component, you gave it the wrong class and for me the result is good?

Comment: I want the first div to stick to the top and then the second below it without overlapping. i purposefully given the same class to them